# FeedItem should show to Chatter FreeUser

Tags: community, chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

When case is created from partner Community User(Partner Communtity Profile), I'm creating record in FeedItem,

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem();
         fi.Body = 'Feed Body';
         fi.ParentId = '5003000000D8cuI';
         fi.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
         fi.NetworkScope = 'AllNetworks';
Insert fi;
```

Now i want this feed to be **shown to Chatter Free** User who is having "***Chatter Free License***".

How can i show this Feed to ChatterUser?
Any Approaches/Workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Chatter Free users don't have access to records. In this example, the feed item is being posted to a Case and Chatter Free users don't have access to Cases. From the [Chatter User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm) documentation:

> The Chatter Free license is for users who don’t have Salesforce
>   licenses but need access to Chatter. These users can access standard
>   Chatter items such as people, profiles, groups, and files, but they
>   can’t access any Salesforce objects or data.

Comment: Yup, i agree.But we can make use of Group. I am posting Feed to group & add chatterFree user and Partner to that group. Here the CHALLENGE is Partner community user unable to see Group created by System admin.

Comment: Yup, I agree.
But I got an idea 




                   FeedItem fi = new FeedItem(); 
                   fi.Body = 'Feed Body';
                    fi.ParentId = 'Some Group Id'; Instead of caseId I have given Group Id
                    fi.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    fi.NetworkScope = 'AllNetworks';  
                    Insert fi;


We can make use of Group. I am posting Feed to group & add chatterFree user and Partner to that group. Here the CHALLENGE is Partner community user unable to see Group created by System admin.


Again I stopped here.

Comment: If the group is a public group, and it's created in the same community as the Partner community user is in, then the Partner community user should be able to access the group. When you insert the FeedItem, make sure fi.NetworkScope is set to the ID of the community.